# Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

This is my code, and when I run this function I get this :`Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array`  However I define `$printed` as an array prior to starting.

```
$printed = array();

function dayAdvance ($startDay, $endDay, $weekType){
         $newdateform = array(
                    'title' => date("M d", strtotime($startDay))."     to     ".date("M d", strtotime($endDay)). $type,
                    'start' => $startDay."T08:00:00Z",
                    'end' => $startDay."T16:00:00Z",
                    'url' => "http://aliahealthcareer.com/calendar/".$_GET['fetching']."/".$startDate);

                    array_push($printed, $newdateform);

        if ($weekType=="weekend"){
            $days="Saturday,Sunday";
        }
        if ($weekType=="day"){
            $days="Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thuresday,Friday";
        }
        if ($weekType=="evening"){
            $days="Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday";
        }
        $start = $startDate;
        while($startDay <= $endDay) {
            $startDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startDay. ' + 1 days'));
            $dayWeek = date("l", strtotime($startDay));
            $pos = strpos($dayWeek, $days);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $newdateform = array(
                    'title' => date("M d", strtotime($start))."     to     ".date("M d", strtotime($endDate)). $type,
                    'start' => $startDate."T08:00:00Z",
                    'end' => $startDate."T16:00:00Z",
                    'url' => "http://aliahealthcareer.com/calendar/".$_GET['fetching']."/".$startDate);

                    array_push($printed, $newdateform);

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: In the current scope, `$printed` was never initialized. Either declare it as `global` or include it in the function parameters.

Comment: [Here's the manual entry on variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the scope in which `array_push()` is called, `$printed` was never initialized. Either declare it as `global` or include it in the function parameters:

```
$printed = array();
.
.
.
function dayAdvance ($startDay, $endDay, $weekType){
    global $printed;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

OR

```
function dayAdvance ($startDay, $endDay, $weekType, $printed = array()) { ... }
```

**NOTE:**

A faster alternative to `array_push()` is to simply append values to your array using `[]`:

```
$printed[] = $newdateform;
```

This method will automatically detect if the variable was never initialized, and convert it to an array prior to appending the data (in other words, no error).

**UPDATE:**

If you want the value of `$printed` to persist outside of the function, you must either pass it by reference or declare it as `global`. The above examples are **NOT** equivalent. The following example would be equivalent to using `global` (and is, in fact, a better practice than using `global` - it forces you to be more deliberate with your code, preventing accidental data manipulation):

```
function dayAdvance ($startDay, $endDay, $weekType, &$printed) { ... }
```

Comment: My understanding of global was off, your first code example cleared it up, I thought you declare global anywhere and not just where you need it. THANKS!

Comment: Please note that it's not recommended to use `global` in this fashion. The better practice is to pass the array by reference. This will prevent unintentionally modifying the data in the future.

Comment: Reason for down-vote? Not only is this answer correct, but it explains proper use of alternative methods, and promotes best practices.

Comment: References are bad in PHP and should be avoided when possible. I would rather just prefer to `return` the `$printed` variable. (Didn't dv though)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `global $printed;` or to add `$printed` as a function parameter.

You may also pass the `$printed` parameter as reference in your function: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

More about global and variable scopes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I tried this and still same issue global `$printed; $printed = array();`

Comment: You need to add global after your function declaration. I have added a link in my questions to know more about variable scopes and globals.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the function `array_push()` use `$your_array[] = $element_to_be_added;` when you want to add a single element to the array.

As mentioned in the docs, this creates a new array, if the array is null:

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.

*and:*

> Note: array_push() will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array. This differs from the $var[] behaviour where a new array is created.

from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

You need validate whit is_array:

Example

```
if (is_array($arNumbers)) {
    $cellid =  array_push($arNumbers, 0);
}
```