# PHP scripts are not working except the Connection

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing a login and registration application in android studio by looking at some of video tutorials,and the php scripts are 100% as in the tutorial and it was working at first time, then now its not working.I can't identify what's gone wrong.. *I am new to php and android*

In the tutorial it's purely working.
Tutorial link >>[Registration app tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArJDXM-HHqk)

spent more than two days for linking database, still stucked over, finally into stackoverflow, Hope for good Solution or Guidance. Thanks

**init.php** which is for Connection, and connection Success

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "blood";
$password = "rifkan123";
$dbname = "userdb";

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);

if(!$con)
{
die("Error in Database Connection".mysqli_connect_error());

}
else
{
Echo "<h3> Database Connection Success !";
}

?>
```

**login.php** Script for login

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
require "init.php";

$query = "Select * userinfo where email like. '".$email."';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$response = array();
$code ="login_true";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$name = $row[0];
$message ="Login Success ! Welcome ".$name;
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
echo json_encode(array(server_response=>$response));    
}
else
{
$response = array();
$code ="login_false";
$message ="Login Failed ! Try Again";
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
echo json_encode(array(server_response=>$response));    
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**register.php** for user registration

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];
require "init.php";

$query = "select * from userinfo where email like '".$email."';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{

$response = array();
$code = "reg_false";
$message = "User Already Exist !";
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));

}
else
{
$query = "insert into userinfo      values('".$name."','".$email."','".$pass."');";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

if(!$result)
{
    $response = array();
    $code = "reg_false";
    $message = "Registration Failed, Try Again!";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
}
else
{
    $response = array();
    $code = "reg_true";
    $message = "Registration Success, Login to Continue!";
    array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
    echo json_encode(array("server_response"=>$response));
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

I have missed the FROM in login script and after adding it new error detected
[Screen shot new Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjQUz.jpg)

Comment: You need to be clearer.  "Not working" tells us nothing.  What's happening-  are they not running at all?  Not returning the right results?  If so what are they doing?

Comment: I made a HTML file to test both registration and login when i run it php scripts displays on the browser

Comment: *Not working* could mean errors, no output at all, or not getting the expected result. Be clear please.

Comment: If PHP scripts display on the browser, there's a configuration problem in your server.  Its treating them as static files rather than programs to run.

Comment: Then what you need to read is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page

Comment: script displays as it is does not give a response the registration success or failed ,

Comment: But at first time everything worked fine, even the database got updated, for this same code

Comment: @RifkanRazak make sure you're opening it using the web server (http://localhost/your/path) and not directly (c:\some\path\yourfile.php)

Comment: @JimL Yah Its open via server

Comment: @RifkanRazak in your screenshot it isn't

Comment: @JimL when i click the Login button the file open as in the screen shot

Comment: To narrow down the source of the problem it would be wise to test each individual piece of code to see where the problem might lie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `FROM` clause in login.php

Here

```
  $query = "Select * from userinfo where email like. '".$email."';";
```

Also consider to add `%%` with like

Comment: Yah Thanks :) But Still the Same

Comment: Where is your login link and login link url , share that code ?

Comment: New error after adding from please check above screen shot

Comment: Congratulation!! you solved your problem as you faced before. For next one check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12204746 and for another next one `best of luck`

Comment: from the above link I solved the first Error Thanks :) Second Error still remains same :(

Comment: Finally login Works :)

Comment: You need to add quotes around like this `"server_response"` you put string directly.

Comment: Yah I found it at Last, now all scripts Works :)